# How to delete margin on right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

can you please check this web address: 120.25.106.212

When the mouse use move you can see a big white margin on the right. If u use a mobile phone to connect to it, it is also not 100% width. How can I cancel this white right margin?

I guess you can check directly my code therefore I do not copy paste entirely here

Comment: Please try to avoid external links, and instead use a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: Your slider images are more thar 2Mb. Optimize them. But it doesn't rely to our question.

Comment: I don't see any big white margin on the right or anywhere else. Can you be more specific? In which browser does this happen?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the external link, reason is because I was not really sure where is the problem and I did not want to copy all of my css and html I just add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every breakpoint you have

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: width;
}
```

You should replace `width` with `max-width`.

Next, you have problems with images at "What's skills can you NI?" block. Add

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much